# Tokenize bank info with Stripe iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Using the UI components in the Stripe iOS SDK, I can easily generate a token/Stripe Source ID client side to securely pass credit card info to the server. I cannot seem to find a similar tokenization feature for bank account info. I can gather bank info client side with STPBankAccountParams, but is there a way to tokenize this info to then pass to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a tokenization method in [`STPAPIAClient`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Stripe/STPAPIClient.m). Is this what you're looking for?

```
#pragma mark - Bank Accounts
@implementation STPAPIClient (BankAccounts)

- (void)createTokenWithBankAccount:(STPBankAccountParams *)bankAccount
                        completion:(STPTokenCompletionBlock)completion {
    NSDictionary *params = [STPFormEncoder dictionaryForObject:bankAccount];
    [self createTokenWithParameters:params completion:completion];
}

@end
```

Comment: Nice! I could not find that. Should be what I need. Appreciate it 