# Create external_account for Stripe Connect payouts with Stripe.js (iOS)

Tags: ios, node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.js

I am trying to connect actual bank accounts to the stripe accounts in Stripe Connect.

However, I am struggling with the actual implementation.

I use Custom Accounts, so I want to provide the user with the account creation logic through my iOS app.

In the Stripe API Reference it says that the recommended way to accomplish this is:
"Destination accounts are added via the external_accounts parameter when creating or updating Custom accounts. The value should be a bank account or debit card token returned from Stripe.js."

Creating the token is documented as follows (I am using NodeJS):

```
stripe.createToken('bank_account', {
  country: 'US',
  currency: 'usd',
  routing_number: '110000000',
  account_number: '000123456789',
  account_holder_name: 'Jenny Rosen',
  account_holder_type: 'individual',
}).then(function(result) {
  // Handle result.error or result.token
});
```

Where to I link that token in the account creation process? See related code below:

```
app.post('/create_account', (req, res) => {
console.log('create account called');
var email = req.body.email;
var firstname = req.body.firstname;
var lastname = req.body.lastname;

stripe.accounts.create({
    country: "CH",
    type: "custom",
    email: email,
    business_name: "examplename",
    legal_entity: {
        first_name: "firstname",
        last_name: "lastname",
        dob: {
            day: 1,
            month: 1,
            year: 1900
        }
    }

}).then((account) => {
    res.status(200).send(account)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, req.body)
    res.status(500).end()
});
});
```

Is the token creation just a means of validating the account information client-side?

Would be glad if someone can elaborate on this with a simple step-by-step explanation, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd pass the token in the [`external_account`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_account-external_account) parameter:

```
var bankAccountToken = req.body.stripeToken;

stripe.accounts.create({
  country: "CH",
  type: "custom",
  // ...
  external_account: bankAccountToken,
}).then((account) => {
  // ...
```

Comment: I did put the "stripe.accounts.create" method inside the result function of "stripe.createToken" (if no error). From there, I pass the token directly to the external_account key. Is that an appropriate way to do it?
Also, my log says: "TypeError: stripe.createToken is not a function"
Where is the problem? Has it something to to with this line:
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script> ?
Thank you Ywain!

Comment: @BesfortAbazi The token should be created in your client-side code using Stripe.js. You'd then send the token ID ("btok_...") to your backend server, and use it to create the account in your server-side Node.js code.

Comment: Would you mind to explain briefly how to implement the code client-side? I do not find documentation on how to do that specifically in an iOS (Objective-C) app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724123/tokenize-bank-info-with-stripe-ios-sdk is this an appropriate solution?

Comment: @BesfortAbazi Right, if your client is an iOS app instead of a web app, you'd need to use Stripe's iOS SDK to tokenize payment information. You can read all about it here: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Comment: I decided to create the token server-side, which I send back to the app. It works well like this, as documented in: https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_bank_account_token
Is it important that it has to be client-side code?
Thank you for the help!
(P.S. the external_account key should be "external_accounts" (with an s, as documented, have not tried if it works without the s as well)

Comment: `external_accounts` (plural) is the name of the attribute returned by the API on account objects. `external_account` (singular) is the name of the parameter that you'd send when creating or updating an account.
If you're going to send the bank account information server-side, you might as well not create a token and directly pass the bank account information in the `external_account` parameter (as a hash instead of a string). But keep in mind that this means you'd be manipulating sensitive payment data, and potentially liable for it.

Comment: Also, you would not be able to add a debit card as an external account this way. For PCI compliance reasons, card data must never hit your server and so must be tokenized client-side.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to create a bank token server side, here it is the way to go:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
  bank_account: {
    country: 'US',
    currency: 'usd',
    account_holder_name: 'Jenny Rosen',
    account_holder_type: 'individual',
    routing_number: '110000000',
    account_number: '000123456789',
  },
});
```

Resource: https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_bank_account?lang=node